# How to define a basic multi-column index associating each entry with a page number

Tags: html, css

Here's what I have in mind:

```
    Alan                  12 | Byron               104
    Alfred                54 | Charles              33
    Ann                   28 | Cleopatra             7
    Basil                133 | Corey               199
    Beryl                  9 | Doris                18
    ...                      |
```

The entries (sorted in alphabetical order) are left-aligned. Each entry is associated with a page number.

This could be a basic index, some form of alphabetical table of contents, a list of diagrams apearing in a book, etc.

Is there any way to achieve this in html without resorting to the use of tables?

Here's a tentative MWE that does **not** give the intended result.

```
<div style="column-count:2; column-gap:1em; column-rule:1px;">                                                                                                              
<div style="display:block;"><span style="display:inline-block; text-align:left;">This is item1</span><span stule="display:inline-block; text-align:right;">123</span></div> 
<div style="display:block;"><span style="display:inline-block; text-align:left;">This is item2</span><span stule="display:inline-block; text-align:right;">125</span></div> 
<div style="display:block;"><span style="display:inline-block; text-align:left;">This is item3</span><span stule="display:inline-block; text-align:right;">137</span></div> 
</div
```

I already have all the data in a file. So it's just a matter of figuring out the correct html/css and writing a five-line script to dress it up and display it.

**Update 10/17/20:**

After fiddling with this for a while I came up with this HTML:

```
<div class="ind-00">
<div class="ind-01"></div>
<div class="ind-02">Alan</div>
<div class="ind-03">621</div>
[...]
</div>
```

... and the corresponding CSS:

```
.ind-01 {
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:1em;
    column-rule:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center !important;
    }
.ind-01 {
    display:table-row;
    text-align:center !important;
    font-family:"Charis SIL Compact, Bold";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:.8em;
    }
.ind-02 {
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-family:"Charis SIL Compact, Regular";
    text-align:left !important;
    text-width:40%;
    }
.ind-03 {
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-family:"Charis SIL Compact, Regular";
    text-align:right !important;
    text-width:20%;
    }
```

The only two epub reading applications on a linux PC I am aware of fail miserably. The calibre suite ebook-viewer program renders this with a single column on the left half of the "page" and the newer Foliate program does display two columns... but with the first half of my lengthy list in column one (about 15 pages with my test sample) and then proceeds to display the second half of the list in column two. In other words, the left column has the entries that start with letters A down to letter 'H' and the second column letters that start with the second half of the entries that start with the letter H all the way to letter Z…! So if the reader is looking for the "Homer" entry there is a good chance that column one, page 15 stops at Holly and he will have to go back 15 pages to be presented with entries Homer-Hyman (e.g.).

I looked at some android epub reading apps and much to my delight the Android Reasily - EPUB Reader correctly renders the above HTML/CSS. The code is apparently smart enough to realize that there is no space left on the "page" (screenful rather) and automatically switches to continue displaying the data **in sequence** in the second column of the current page. Other android apps I took a look at are a mixed bag. Gitgen does it correctly (with my sample index data) but most either display a single column (FBReader, AIReader, Readera) and those that attempt multi-column mode are not smart enough to switch to the second column **on the same page**.

Comment: It's a table. Use that

Answer (score 0):

Your data is indeed in a tabular form, so tables is the best option, IMO. By wrapping the left and right tables within a div with flex display, both tables will render side by side instead of one on top of the other. Then each table needs to take 50% of the width.

```css
body > div {
  display: flex;
}

body > div > table {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Alan</td><td>12</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Alfred</td><td>54</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Byron</td><td>12</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Charles</td><td>54</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if you REALLY want to use divs...

```css
body > div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

body > div > div {
  flex: 1;
}

body > div > div > div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

body > div > div > div > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div><div>Alan</div><div>12</div></div>
    <div><div>Alfred</div><div>54</div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><div>Byron</div><div>104</div></div>
    <div><div>Charles</div><div>33</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with flux and I was unable to find a clear description online. But I see a problem with both solutions: They do not display one list in multicolumn mode but rather they arbitrarily divide the 'Alan -> Charles...' list into two lists of equal lengths and display them side by side. The consequence (unless I am mistaken) is that if at a later stage one of the half-lists increases by... say, 100 entries the entire html code has to be recreated in order to balance the two lists. Otherwise I will end up with — e.g. a few pages at the end with an empty column.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I do not understand it... another reason I would prefer to avoid using flexbox is that I am unsure how well it is supported especially by the limited html/css implementations on e-readers, tablets... etc. And there is no way I can verify that save for testing it on every ereading device and every ereading application on the market.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that this is an epub?

Comment: Sorry... when I hit the Enter key it posts the message instead of starting a new paragraph. To clarify: I have a list with c. 1500 pairs of the form [entry1, page#1] etc. I need the pair to be displayed as in my original post with entry1 left-aligned and page#1 right-aligned. Now since entry1+page#1 is pretty short I would need some way to tell the code that interprets the html that when it runs out of space on the current page, it should not continue on the following page but rather move to the second column. See what happens when Byron follows Beryl in my original post.

Comment: The consequence of this is that there should be some way to tell the code that interprets the html+css that it should write the data in the first column until it reaches the maximum length of the "page" and then switch to the second column... continue until it reaches the maximum allowed again and then continue on page 2, column 1. etc. until it reaches the end of the data. Obviously since behind the scenes html is made up of what amounts to scrolls rather than pages this has to be faked somehow.

Comment: Okay so you have a program that is able to render this on the fly, or just renders it once for later? You mention epub files, are you talking about a loading this on an epub reader app, kindle or nook? If this is the case, I don't think you need to break the table at all, the epub reader software should take care of paging; the fact that you swipe left or right does not mean that the content is actually on the left or right. BTW, if this is about an ePub file, I think you'll have better luck getting an answer with a new questions with those tags.

Comment: You are right. Since it's the epub reader software that simulates pages it's up to the epub reader software to take care of the paging as requested in the outside <div></div> and the associatedd CSS style (column-count=2; column-gap.. etc.). Something most do not do correctly as I found out. Now that I understand my problem a little better I see that this question initially belonged in the epub group. I'll keep that in mind next time around.

Comment: I opened an issue on the  johnfactotum/foliate github site and the developer informs me that the culprit is the webkit web engine. Which explains why some android apps get it right and others do not.

Comment: That makes sense. Have you tried a table? I think it is a more standard way to present tabular content.

Comment: Well… the problem is that with a table the list must be split down the middle (for two columns). It means that you need code somewhere to rearrange your two sublists in the event you add (or remove) items from (mostly) one or the other sub-lists. Otherwise you will end up with a half-filled or even blank column(s) on the last page(s). So it's a possible workaround but I wouldn't call it multi-column… btw the foliate issue I opened with foliate is #611.  with interesting remarks from its developer.

Comment: Isn't your data a Name/Value list? why do you HAVE to present it in two pairs of columns side by side? epub files can be loaded in devices with small screens where the software decides the number of characters to present per line. If your table is too wide, there is a risk that these devices won't be able to present it at all. A taller table with just one pair of columns would allow the device to better handle the presentation. My two cents...

Comment: If this table is meant to never change and needs to be produced just once, another option is to embed it as an image, with the exact format you want it to be. smaller screens would just shrink the image so that it fits the width of the screen.

Comment: This is the equivalent of a basic index <item><page>. Some 1500 of those and each comparatively short. The original book (a large-ish in-quarto) uses three columns because a huge blank space would look rather ugly and  more importantly confuse the reader's eye as to what item and what page number are on the same line. Besides I just want to do multi-column :) As to images I reserve this for cases where the layout is really complex. Beside they are not searchable.